# FaceBook JS SDK: callback functions on "Captive Portal Login" android browser are never called

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, browser

Writing some JS code for my HotSpot network. The idea is: user is connecting to my wireless access point after which he will be transferred to my HotSpot login page. The page contains FaceBook share button which gives an access to internet after successful post sharing on his FaceBook page by calling a callback function passed as parameter of FB.ui function. When I tested this by my Android device which uses "Captive Portal Login" browser to redirect to the login page I found a problem: passed callback functions are never called by SDK on this browser. I have tested separately both "FB.ui" function and "FB.login" function: passed callback functions are never called. When i use "chrome" browser on my Android - it works fine! But I need this to work on "Captive Portal Login" browser because this is a public network and I can't force all connected Android devices to use chrome. Any solutions? Thank You!

Here is the required part of my code:

```
<head>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"><script>
</head>

<script>
    $(function () {
        session.FB_async_init();
    })


    var session = {

        FB_async_init: function () {
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '*my app Id*',
                    autoLogAppEvents: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v8.0'
                });
            };
        },

        FB_post_feed: function () {
            FB.login(function(loginResponse) {     /*here is the login callback which is never being called*/
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    display: 'touch',
                    link: '*my share link*',
                }, function(feedResponse) {
                    *code of the callback function. Also is not being called even the FB.ui function used separately*
                })
            })
        }

    }

</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <img class="facebook-share-button" src="~/img/fbshare.png" onclick="session.FB_post_feed()" />
    </div>
</body>
```

P.S. Directly shares and login work fine! Only callback functions are not called

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to give the user anything for posting.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but user Does can make posts using FaceBook SDK! I'm talking about only that the callback functions I pass as parameters are not being called after successful sharing. Unfortunately I don't know any ways to open any dev panel using CaptivePortalLogin app on Android so I can't debug my code and see errors

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to give the user anything for posting. So of course there will not be any callback telling you that they shared it. And even if they did you are not allowed to do it. So if you did you app would be banned